# Selinum Driver wait for SVG to be completely rendred

Tags: python, svg, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with Chrome driver to scrap pages that contain SVG . 
I need a way to make Selenium wait until the svg is completely loaded otherwise I will get some incomplete charts when I scrap.

For the moment the script wait for 10sec before it start scrapping but that's is a lot for scraping 20000 pages .

```
 def page_loaded(driver):
        path = "//*[local-name() = 'svg']"
        time.sleep(10)
        return driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)

 wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
 wait.until(page_loaded)
```

is there any efficient way to check if the SVG is loaded before starting to scrap?

Comment: I believe you are looking for `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`

Comment: I'm already using that with the above function as a condition to stop waiting . 
code updated

Answer (score -1):

An example from Selenium documentation:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

So in your case it should be :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
```

Here `10` in `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` is the maximum seconds of wait. ie it waits until 10 or condition whichever is first.

Some common conditions that are frequently of use when automating web browsers:

- title_is title_contains
- presence_of_element_located
- visibility_of_element_located visibility_of
- presence_of_all_elements_located
- text_to_be_present_in_element
- text_to_be_present_in_element_value
  etc.
  [More available here.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

[Also here's the documentation for expected conditions support.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

Another way you can tackle this is write your on method like:

```
def find_svg(driver):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
    if element:
        return element
    else:
        return False
```

And then call Webdriver wait like:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, max_secs).until(find_svg)
```

Comment: My code does exactly what you wrote . it wait for svg to appear  but the problem is I want to wait for it to be rendred by the browser . the code you wrote doesn't do that it just check if an element exist not if is it completely rendred . and when I say 10 sec I mean the `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: What is your exact usecase? Maybe you should add more info like html_source. This is a suggestion. If the svg element has a certain height and width you can check for that?  Or by size?

Comment: This is an interesting problem anyway. Here's a link that might help you. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/verifying-if-an-image-is-displayed-on-a-webpage

Comment: the problem is the svg content not the svg tag it self . if you don't wait for it content to be rendred ( which varies from page to page ) you wont get it correct when you scrap .

Comment: Are you trying to download the svg content? If so, then scrape the `src` attribute and download from that link.

Comment: yes but svg has no source attribute ..the browser draw it with javascript based on some server side data